# Как скачать справку локально Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

Каждый раз ждать подгрузку справки ctrl + q долго и требуется подключение к интернет, а он не всегда есть.
Возможно ли как то скачать справку по Java локально на комп?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чисто гипотетически так можно попробовать, но стоит ли заморачиваться - https://www.dynamsoft.com/codepool/java-documentation-android-studio-export-import.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось что если скачать последний Android SDK то справка тоже скачается:)

Answer (score -1):

Данная генерация справки ,  это комментарий оформленные в коде . В IDE можете перейти к данному участку кода через ctrl + левый щелчок мышки.